# ExtJS4 AJAX request is cross domain

Tags: ajax, extjs, extjs4, cross-domain

I am trying to post to a server listening on a different port, but FireFox insists on sending an OPTIONS request because apparently I am not using the proper URL. How can I POST to  localhost:8161 without FireFox thinking the request might be cross domain and sending OPTIONS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you have an answer:

[How do I send a cross-domain POST request via JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/298745/how-do-i-send-a-cross-domain-post-request-via-javascript)

It is not easy to detail it in a better way.

Comment: Thanks!  I've been searching for this - not well, but searching nevertheless.

Answer (score 0):

You can add iframe whose src contains url with different port

Comment: Thanks, but I want to POST.